# Parsing for a dynamic json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have json which I am trying to parse using Jackson. JSON looks as -

```
coupons: {
  1: {
     title: "Mode von",
     description: "",
     type: "offer",
     code: "-",
     expiry: "0000-00-00",
     link: ""
  },    
  2: {
     title: "Prime 1",
     description: "",
     type: "offer",
     code: "-",
     expiry: "0000-00-00",
     link: "http://test.com/"
  }
}
```

The number of coupons are not constant here and would vary from response to response.
My dilemma is to create corresponding java class which could hold such object.

I tried with Map as -

```
public class Coupons {
   Map<String, String>coupons = new HashMap<String, String>();
   public Map<String, String> getCoupons() {
      return coupons;
   }
}
```

But -

```
System.out.println(coupons.getCoupons().get("type"));
System.out.println(coupons.getCoupons().get("code"));
```

always get me null. What would be right java class for this json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first level of keys are the index numbers 1, 2, 3, etc.
so in order to get the type and code, you have to specificy the key.

you could do this:

```
var coupons = coupons.getCoupons(); //<--breakpoint to see if this is really populated.
foreach( String key in coupons.Keys ){ //<- pseudo code, iterate over keys  
  var obj = coupons.get(key);
  var type = obj.get("type");
  etc..
}
```

hope this helps you move on

Comment: I think I can not just do - `Map<String, String>coupons = new HashMap<String, String>();` as `coupons.getCoupons()` does not get me any Map object

Comment: ok, I changed the map to - `private Map<String, Map<String, String>>coupons = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();` But the key of solution was to get the key of the key of the map as you suggested.